# How to detect elements overlapping (overlaying) using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to detect overlap HTML elements, using JavaScript?

I have an item list (`<ul>`). It slides up and down using JavaScript. When it slides down, depending on number of item, it may overlap the other element (`<div>`), which is absolute positioned at this time (it can be changed).

How I can detect, when `<ul>` overlaps this `<div>`, to apply new style to the `<div>` to hide it temporary or to move it down a little bit, to prevent overlapping?
It's just not looking good, when they overlap))

Here you can see, what I'm talking about: http://timetable.raj.fvds.ru/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have absolutely positioned elements, then it's not trivial - you need to calculate each elements position etc. and act accordingly. Maybe you should consider achieving the same effect without absolutes, maybe some mix of floats (float:left) and absolutes (position:absolute) inside relatives (position:relative).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function isObjOnObj(a,b){
    var al = a.left;
    var ar = a.left+a.width;
    var bl = b.left;
    var br = b.left+b.width;

    var at = a.top;
    var ab = a.top+a.height;
    var bt = b.top;
    var bb = b.top+b.height;

    if(bl>ar || br<al){return false;}//overlap not possible
    if(bt>ab || bb<at){return false;}//overlap not possible

    if(bl>al && bl<ar){return true;}
    if(br>al && br<ar){return true;}

    if(bt>at && bt<ab){return true;}
    if(bb>at && bb<ab){return true;}

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Um... If that's pseudo-code, sure.  You need to check the position of all the `offsetParent`s, get the `offsetWidth`, `offsetHeight`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This feels like collision detection, and there's a solution just posted. Instead, I would suggest working out how many list items would be needed for a menu to overlap (i.e. 10), and hide the `div` when those menus (with 10 `li`) are selected.

Comment: It's impossible, on different site pages amount of list items and its content is different, so on some pages item list takes really much place.

Comment: The content of the list items or the page? If the list items are uniform in height, then you can still work out that 10 items will overlap a `div` at `top:100px`, therefore 5 items overlap `top:50px` etc. You'd write a function to take the number of items, and position of the `div`, and decide whether to hide. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Heh. You could factor the current window width into the equation for when the list items wrap. (And, of course, the text size and text length.) What's your current thinking?

Comment: Unfortunately, list items aren't uniform in height, because its content moves to a new line, depending on window width, so in my case this method is almost useless. I think, the best way is to calculate element's positions and check if they matched, like ChrisThompson offered above. I'd tried such method using JQuery before, but position calculations somehow were wrong, maybe I've just made a mistake, but function looked correct.

Comment: Sounds good, but I suppose this method much more complicated, then just calculating element's positions.