# How can I detect an overlapping elements using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I detect that an element has overlapped another ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect elements overlapping (overlaying) using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720837/how-to-detect-elements-overlapping-overlaying-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this useful plugin https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-overlaps