# Determine if one node is overlapping another

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to know, in jQuery, if a node is overlapping another?

Comment: Define `above` and `below` with regards to the DOM?

Comment: On top of David Thomas' question, how are you selecting the nodes to begin with?

Comment: Yeah, definitely define `above` and `below`, since you got three different answers, based on three different meanings for "`above`" and "`below`"...

Comment: Do you mean which has higher or lower vertical placement on the screen (offset), which of several siblings appears first in the DOM (index), which occurs first in the DOM overall (some sort of recursive use of index), or which is in front/behind (z-index)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want to detect overlapping? Then this:

```
var overlaps = (function () {
    function getPositions( elem ) {
        var pos, width, height;
        pos = $( elem ).position();
        width = $( elem ).width();
        height = $( elem ).height();
        return [ [ pos.left, pos.left + width ], [ pos.top, pos.top + height ] ];
    }

    function comparePositions( p1, p2 ) {
        var r1, r2;
        r1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
        r2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
        return r1[1] > r2[0] || r1[0] === r2[0];
    }

    return function ( a, b ) {
        var pos1 = getPositions( a ),
            pos2 = getPositions( b );
        return comparePositions( pos1[0], pos2[0] ) && 
               comparePositions( pos1[1], pos2[1] );
    };
})();
```

Usage:

```
if ( overlaps( node1, node2 ) ) {
    // ...
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/98sAG/

Comment: `offset()` is a bit more efficient.

Comment: Sorry I see the example that was posted now. Good answer

Comment: Thank you for this. I used this snippet in a rudimentary game I'm making (as a demo for a client) and it has saved me a lot of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.offset()` to find its position on the screen:

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

With `offset();` you will be able to get a Y coordinate called `top` that will be its location in pixels from the top of the window.

```
var boxOne = $('#boxOne').offset():
var boxTwo = $('#boxTwo').offset():

if(boxOne.top>boxTwo.top) {
    alert('boxOne is higher');
} else if (boxOne.top==boxTwo.top) {
    alert('boxes are even');
} else {
    alert('boxTwo is higher');
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to detect [overlapping](http://data.imagup.com/11/1138998080.png), not which node is higher in the document.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function .index() in jQuery which does what you are looking for I guess. 
Here is a link to the page:

http://api.jquery.com/index/

If you have any specific questions about the function feel free to ask.

Comment: Damn, you were faster.. I just found `.index()` in the docs and yeah, it looks like it is the right way to do that..

Comment: I know .index() this is not what i am looking for :)

I want to do this : http://data.imagup.com/11/1138998080.png

Answer (score 0):

For position in DOM, I don't think `index()` is enough, unless you are comparing two sister elements. More generally,

- Use `parents()` on both nodes
- pop off elements from both ancestor lists while identical
- compare `index()` on the highest differing ancestor

(Alternately, you could also do `index()` on `$('*')`, but I guess that would be horribly inefficient)

EDIT: with the clarification under @Mike's answer, this is now officially a collision detection question. Thus, I think something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720837/how-to-detect-elements-overlapping-overlaying-using-javascript) is in order, but note the comment. You can instead use the jQuery [`offset()` function](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to get the position of the elements. The comparison logic is sound.