# in jQuery how to determine whether one or more div elements overlap and cover completely another div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, geometry, collision-detection, computational-geometry

If I have a DIV element (the blu square B in the figure) absolutely positioned in the document and overlapped on another DIV (blank square A), then I can get if B cover completely A by comparing x1,y1,x2,y2 region of B with A.

However, if one or more B squares overlap A, how can I get if A is completely covered?

I cannot merge B1 and B2 regions then compare it with A because some areas may be still uncovered (as red areas in the figure).

In Flash there are some methods that simplify the calculation of regions but I don't figure out how to do it in jQuery.

[image]

Comment: This problem is essentially agnostic from jQuery, and will probably be best answered in programmers.stackexchange.com :D

Comment: Try to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560926/efficiently-detect-when-sibling-elements-overlap

Comment: findIntersectors(targetSelector, intersectorsSelector) is an elegant function to get collisions, but I'm looking for some code to get if an item is completely covered/overlapped (visible/invisible). Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no approach to this using just jQuery, however you can play with z-indexes of the elements and the position respect to the window http://api.jquery.com/position/

Also I found a solution in Javascript which might help you:

[How to detect elements overlapping (overlaying) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720837/how-to-detect-elements-overlapping-overlaying-using-javascript)